# Ionic 4 form fields with *ngIf

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an array of objects, form fields like so:

```
public fields: FormField[];
```

each object looks like this:

```
{
    label: "Name",
    id: "284754890",
    type: "text" <-- or checkbox, email etc
}
```

I am building the form view by looping the fields as follows:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let field of fields">
        <ion-label>{{ field.label }}</ion-label>
        <ion-input *ngIf="field.type == 'text'" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**The problem i am having is that all the fields in the array are displaying, even if their "type" property isn't "text" - it seems like the *ngIf isn't working on the input field?
I have also tried the *ngIf on a div wrapping around the input but it still isn't working.**

Comment: use like this [type]="field.type"

Comment: @user9088454 Thanks, but that isn't going to work on say a select element

Comment: looks like it should work - is field.label populating (eg you have correct data being read) - have you tried `<ion-label>{{ field.type }}</ion-label>` to be sure the value you expect is being passed?